# Unit testing output, depending on Math.random()

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

I have some functions in a Node.js application whose output depends on `Math.random()`. Is it possible to unit test these functions? If so, what is the best strategy?

For example, one function I have selects a random integer with weights.

```
var getRandomFeature = function (featureWeights) {
  var u,
      i,
      cumSum = 0;

  u = Math.random();

  for (i = 0; i < featureWeights.length; i++) {
    cumSum += featureWeights[i];

    if (cumSum > u) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  return (featureWeights.length - 1);
};

console.log(getRandomFeature([0.7, 0.3]));
```

Comment: Yes, but you would need to post the functions to get more precise help. A better way to do it is to mock `Math.random` or simply test that your functions perform correctly for selected inputs.